# Increase drop chances based on the number

Tags: math, random

Good day, there is a task. Take the number N (from 1 to 1000)

From a random function, we need a number R from 1 to 1,000,000

Moreover, if R = 950,000-990,000. Then we get a unique item
And if 990,000-1,000,000 then a legendary item falls to us

Problem. Come up with math so that with an increase in N, the chance of dropping unique and legendary items increases.

I would like to hear your solutions, because I did not think of mine. Thank!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should ask it on math.stackexchange.com, rather than here.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a function F(N) that returns R? How about `F(N)=random(900,000) + 100 N` ?